# Is 'surface street' specific to southern California?

Tags: american-english, dialects

In Los Angeles, California, the US, the phrase *surface street* is in common use.  It refers to an ordinary city street, as opposed to a controlled-access *freeway*.  Presumably the word *surface* comes from the fact that these streets are at ground level, whereas freeways are often elevated.

I suppose I first heard this phrase somewhere in southern California, but assumed it was a standard term that I just happened to be hearing for the first time.  But I have now seen claims that *surface street* is specifically local to Los Angeles and the vicinity ([example from the LA Times](http://articles.latimes.com/2011/jul/10/opinion/la-oe-0710-long-carmeggedon-20110710)).

- Is the use of *surface street* localized only to southern California, or is it in general use anywhere else?
- Are there other common terms (either widespread or localized to other places) for a street or road which emphasize that it is not a freeway?

Comment: If there are better tags, please feel free to add them.  I looked for a "local-dialect" tag but did not find it.

Comment: It's definitely used in the northeast. Or, at least, my friends use it here. They also use "local streets".

Comment: I’m not sure where that author gets it.  I’ve heard ***surface streets *** used many other places.

Comment: We use it in Northern California (or more accurately, the San Francisco Bay Area), too. I suspect that the tendency of route-mapping software to prefer freeway routes has led to greater consciousness of the term "surface streets" among people who would rather avoid freeways.

Comment: @Dan: I've lived in both Southern California and the Northeast, and I suspect that the reason you hear it is that you have friends from California. In my experience, most Northeasterners don't use it. And it is certainly ***much*** more common in Southern California than the Northeast.

Comment: The term is recognized throughout most of the US.  Of course in many areas the term would be little-used, since it's an irrelevant distinction without subways or elevated highways of some sort.

Comment: @HotLicks I am a 47-year-old northeasterner who has never before now heard of "surface street" meaning non-controlled-access street, despite having had more than a handful of friends from California (mostly from the San Francisco Bay area).  I would have assumed that it denotes urban roadways that are neither tunnels nor viaducts.

Comment: @phoog - I'm 66 years old and from Kentucky, currently residing in Minnesota.  I've spent a grand total of about 4 weeks in California in my lifetime.  I'm quite familiar with the term.

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't mean to challenge the truth of your statement, just to offer a counterexample for anyone inclined to interpret it as meaning "would be recognized by any American.". Also, since "street" means "urban roadway" and the meaning of "surface" is self evident, it may just be that uses of "surface street" to denote a roadway that *isn't* an urban roadway on the surface are very rare.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I heard "surface street" as a child growing up in Detroit.  The meaning was exactly as in the question (except that our freeways tended to be below the rest of the ground rather than elevated).

Answer (score 6):

[Surface Streets](http://golosangeles.about.com/od/latravelplanning/ss/Driving-In-Los-Angeles_2.htm) Kayte Deioma, *Driving in Los Angeles: Los Angeles Driving Vocabulary*, about.com

> In Los Angeles, the term "surface street" refers to any normal street that is not a freeway or limited access highway.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surface_street)

> A street that is not a freeway and has at-grade intersections with other surface streets.

The Wiktionary definition agrees with the idea of "ordinary city street, that is not a freeway; is at ground level, unlike elevated freeways," while the vocabulary seems to suggest that the term is local to Los Angeles, CA.

However, *surface street* is a **standard term** in engineering, including transportation, highway engineering, railways, etc., and is not specific to LA, or even to CA.

Steven Kuhrtz, US EPA *Transportation controls*, 1974

> "… surface street bus lanes in Atlanta, Birmingham, and Baltimore have increased auto speeds more than bus speeds."

[Traffic Analysis Toolbox](http://ops.fhwa.dot.gov/trafficanalysistools/tat_vol4/app_k.htm) US DoT FHA, 2007
"… a surface street section inserted in a freeway interchange to allow merging of ramp lanes"
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The term "*surface street*" appears to have originated towards the end of the 19th century in the proposals to build urban railways; in order to distinguish the ground level from underground and elevated systems.

For example, the 1867 [report](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5EYpAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22surface%20street%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DASIVdexJPLM7Qabxq2oAg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22surface%20street%22&f=false) of the "*Special commission to ascertain the best means for the transportation of passengers in the city of New York*" in 1867 proposes building an underground railway system with a "surface street" above it at ground level.

There are many other references from the late 19th century (from Chicago, New York and other cities), all of which are referring to ground-level roads as "surface street". So to answer the first question, it appears that the term is not localised to Southern California, but is in widespread use elsewhere.  As to other localised expressions for the same thing, I do not know.

Comment: +1, though I think you might want to clarify your paenultimate sense a bit. Answering “Yes” to whether something is A or B is logical, but rarely satisfies the querent. ;-)

Comment: Well spotted, Janus. I've fixed it, and also googled "querent" in the process.